# Javascript Code will not click each element of an accordion

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a script that will find every part of an accordion and click it, after this code runs I will scrape. But, I am having issues with each part being clicked, only a few do or only on the very last element is all the clicking be done.

The url is: https://www.vikingrivercruises.com/cruise-destinations/europe/danube-waltz/2022-budapest-passau/pricing.html

The code I am using is:

```
var elements_accordion = document.querySelectorAll('[data-bind="text: priceRange"]');
for(var i = 0; i < elements_accordion.length;i++) 
{
    async function output_print(i) 
    {
        await elements_accordion[i].click(); 
        await console.log("Doing number: "+i); 
    } 
    async function timeOutFn(i) { await setTimeout(output_print, 50000, i); }
    timeOutFn(i);    
}
```

Further, if I input into the console: elements_accordion[1].click() it does what I want but not when it goes into a for loop. I was thinking its an asynchronous issue, but only occasionally does it work 100%.

Any help would be great.

Comment: First of all i suggest you to don't use for loop but forEach and don't create function into that but create it outside and use it inside for loop. 
Second if i inspect your page i can see for example that:`<span class="cruise-pricing" data-bind="text: 'From ' + priceRange">From £1,695</span>` seems like it's print priceRange as text instead of value of variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var moreInfoElements = document.getElementsByClassName("more-info");
var timeDelay = 4000;

x=0;
while(x<moreInfoElements.length) {
    setTimeout(clickMe,timeDelay*x,moreInfoElements[x],x);
    x++;
}

function clickMe(elemToClick,num) {
    console.log("clicking "+(num+1)+" out of "+moreInfoElements.length);
    elemToClick.click();
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. It works after making a few tweaks for performance. It's strange because the logic was very similar to several of my variations but the while loop and setTimeout somehow worked for you...

Answer (score 1):

- There is no point in using **async/await** logic on `console.log`,
  `click`, and `setTimeout` function because these functions don't
  return Promise.
  Here is the working example with proper `sleepFn` function which returns a promise.

```js
    const accordion_elements = document.querySelectorAll('tr.hidden-tn.hidden-xs');
    
    const sleepFn = ms => new Promise((res) => setTimeout(() => res(), ms));

    accordion_elements.forEach(async function(item) {
          await sleepFn(1000); 
          item.click()
        }
    );
```

Comment: Oops. Looks like I need a bit more time to get this one correct.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate this so much! But, it still does not click each element.

Comment: Looks like the loop just stops when there is a network call comes in between. When we click accordion for the first time after the page is loaded, the browser makes a network request to load the data. But if you click all accordions first, then run your code it works fine.

Comment: I had noticed that if I clicked on them manually and ran them it worked...I also noticed if I call them individually they also worked thats why I was thinking I needed a time delay to make this work. I'm so frustrated by this.

Comment: I also noticed the site produces an error initially:

"Refused to execute script from 'https://sp.analytics.yahoo.com/sp.pl?a=10000&b=Danube%20Waltz%20River%20Cruise%20Dates%20and%20Pricing%20-%202022%20Budapest%20to%20Passau&.yp=431785&f=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.vikingrivercruises.com%2Fcruise-destinations%2Feurope%2Fdanube-waltz%2F2022-budapest-passau%2Fpricing.html&enc=UTF-8&et=custom&tagmgr=tealium%2Cgtm' because its MIME type ('') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled. " I am wondering if this has anything to do with it?